# Why is there white stuff on these inductors?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

[image]

Why are these inductors covered with white stuff?

1. Is this to reduce EMI/EMC?
2. To reduce of unwanted noise?

Whatever it is, please explain it.

Answer (score 13):

The windings on the inductors can move just a tiny bit, especially if there's a lot of current flowing through the coil.  The magnetic field generated by the current flowing in the coil makes the wires move.  If the current varies at a frequency that the ear can hear, then the coils will "whine" - they make an audible noise.

The white stuff is to deaden the mechanical vibration from the inductors.

Answer (score 11):

It is to prevent the coils from oscillating (mechanically).
You may know that from GPUs "coil whine"

Comment: Is it just glue?

Comment: Did you mean "PSU"? A GPU is a microchip, it has no coils (though coils may be present on a graphics card).

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate some sort of non-conductive silicone or resin normally

Answer (score 5):

Check how the coils are fastened to the board. They can be too heavy to be held only by a couple of thin soldered wires. I have seen how parts vibrate themselves out of the circuit when there's nothing else keeping them fastened than soldered straight wires in the holes of the PCB. The vibrations were caused by moving the device daily on a car seat, not even in the trunk.

In audio speakers, vehicles and machines the normal operation can be too violent for poorly fastened parts. Coils can vibrate also due the magnetic forces caused by the pulse currents.

You probably see in the future many devices which have parts which are glued to the circuit board with a big splash of white glue.

Answer (score 3):

Officially, the white stuff is called "Potting Compound" and is intended to physically prevent things moving, and/or protect them from being tampered with.

Other answers have explained this specific case, but you will also come across it on many other (mainly quite old) circuit boards with discrete components, particularly where large/heavy items might get shaken loose, eg capacitors on a portable radio.

Comment: Is that really the same as potting compound? My understanding is that potting compound is quite thin before curing (so it can thoroughly fill in the gaps being potted), but that would make it less useful as a spot-applied adhesive.

Comment: @Sneftel   AFTER curing, potting compound gets fairly solid, and this stops things moving - more 'filler' than 'adhesive'.

Comment: Thanks, I’m aware of how curing works. I was referring to the pre-curing viscosity, which (I would think) would be too low with potting compound to partially ‘bury’ the component on the flat board surface without flowing away.

Comment: I have several old boards in my attic that demonstrate what I describe. No doubt it comes in a variety of grades and formulations, intended for different circumstances.

Comment: Wouldn’t the only expected circumstance be “potting a circuit”? I can’t really see why certain PCBs would require or benefit from something other than a low viscosity while being potted. And I can’t see why that viscosity would also be optimal or even reasonable for things other than potting.

Comment: The answers above mention one use, I've already mentioned another. Additionally I believe it is sometimes used to prevent trimmers from being adjusted after completion; sometimes used as a weather-proofing agent, and also in some cases I believe it was done to obfuscate the circuit itself (though clearly that would be of limited use.)

Comment: I've always thought that potting compound was the stuff that they poured into potted elements. I would call that white stuff Silastic.

Comment: Silastic is a trademarked name for a specific compound, not a generic term.